# How to tokenise the output of command and store in linked list of variables?

Tags: c

I wrote a python script which gives output as mentioned below.

```
interface   mac_address         ip_address        rx_bytes         rx_packets       start_time    end_time    
eth3        01:00:02:20:cd:d3   122.168.12.12       648              8                1531167452.33  1531167452.36
eth2        03:00:02:b5:ef:7e   122.168.3.14       75303498         843297           1531167452.33  1531167452.36
eth1        04:00:02:25:6c:b1   122.168.2.15       76756884         846595           1531167452.33  1531167452.36
```

I am calling this python script from C program using execlp system call and would like to store the each tokenised (i.e. interface name, mac etc..) value in to a structure link list. I could able to call the python script from C program, but i am not sure how to parse this output and store in a linklist structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void) 
{
  pid_t child;
  pid_t c; /* Pid of child to be returned by wait. */
  int cstatus;
  int stdout_fds[2];
  char foo[4096 + 1];
  int rc;


  int nbytes = 0;

  memset(foo, 0, 4096);


  rc = pipe(stdout_fds);
  if (rc != 0) {
    printf("pipe() failed \n");
    return;
  }


  if ((child = fork()) == 0) {

     /* Child process. To begin with, it prints its pid. */
     printf("Child process executes the commandi");
     close(stdout_fds[0]);
     dup2(stdout_fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

     /* Child will now execute */
     execlp("/usr/bin/python", "python", "counters.py", NULL);

     fprintf(stderr, "Child process could not do execlp.\n");

     close(stdout_fds[1]);

     exit(1);
  }
  else 
  { 
     /* Parent process. */
     if (child == (pid_t)(-1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed.\n"); exit(1);
     }
     else 
     {
        close(stdout_fds[1]);

        while(0 != (nbytes = read(stdout_fds[0], foo, sizeof(foo)))) {
          printf("%s", foo);
          memset(foo, 0, 4096);
        }

       c = waitpid(child, &cstatus, 0); /* Wait for child to complete. */
       printf("Parent: Child %ld exited with status = %d\n",(long) c, cstatus);
     }
  }
  return 0;
} /* End of main. */

[root@ ~]# ./test.exe 
 interface   mac_address         ip_address        rx_bytes         rx_packets       start_time    end_time    
eth3        01:00:02:20:cd:d3   122.168.12.12       648              8                1531167452.33  1531167452.36
eth2        03:00:02:b5:ef:7e   122.168.3.14       75303498         843297           1531167452.33  1531167452.36
eth1        04:00:02:25:6c:b1   122.168.2.15       76756884         846595           1531167452.33  1531167452.36
```

From the above output, would like to read each line and tokenise each value and store in structure and represent in a link list. Could any one throw some light of best optimization technique for doing the same.

**Example of struct:**

```
struct entry
{ 
   char interface_name[24];
   char mac[32];
   char ip_address[40];
   char rx_bytes[256];
   char rx_packets[256]; 
   char start_time[256];
   char end_time[256];
}p[3];

p[0] -> p[1] -> p[3]
```

Comment: how are the fields in the output delimited? Is it using tabs or is it using spaces to line fixed font text up into columns?

Comment: The delimiter is spaces. The values are being separated by spaces. No need to parse the first line of output. The remaining three lines needed to tokenised and store in a structure. right now, I am looking in to a strtok() operator.

Comment: Why do you need list? Isn't array enough? Why can't you just use `for (i in output lines) { sscanf(foo, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", p[i].interface_name, p[i].mac, p[i].ip_address, p[i].rx_bytes, p[i].rx_packets, p[i].start_time,p[i].end_time); }`?

Comment: The problem you will have with strtok is distinguishing between the field separator (spaces) and the line terminator (a newline), because strtok does not tell you which of the delimiter characters was at the end of the token before it was overwritten with a NUL. However, it is easy enough to use `strspn` and `strcspn` (and in fact, you could implement strtok with those in a couple of lines of code).

Comment: @kamilCuk: Because nothing guarantees that `foo` will be exactly one line of input.

Comment: Here, i observe that skipping the first line seems to be tricky with strtok and parsing the remaining output (expect first line) to store in to different variables present in structure.

Comment: @john: On the contrary, skipping the first line is trivial *provided you have all the data*. It's the second and subsequent lines which are the problem, unless you are prepared to assume that the data will always have the same number of tokens on every line.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: i closed both  close(stdout_fds[0]);  close(stdout_fds[1]); file descriptors in child. What else i need to close here

Comment: @john517501: you never close(stdout_fds[1]) in the child -- the code after the execlp call never runs...

Comment: How to make the above program as non blocking read? instead of blocking?